# How to reformat a pendrive on Win 7?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, usb-flash-drive, format

I've performed a low level format on a pendrive using Active@kill disk utility.  However, when I tried to re-format it using Windows 7 system, it is unable to accept the drive. I get an error that Windows cannot format the drive.

I tried to use the software from the same developer called Active Partition Manager but it is unable to create the partition.

Is there a way to diagnose the problem and reformat this pendrive?  It worked flawlessly prior to the low level format.

Comment: Did you create a new partition table, like MBR (or maybe GPT)?

Comment: I did (MBR) but then the software (Partition manager) did not let me to format the device and showed it as zero in capacity.

Answer (score 1):

Use the DiskPart.exe program to do this which will give you the most control.

For example, to create USB flash drive that is bootable (MBR for non UEFI) do the following:

1. DiskPart [this will take you into the DiskPart console)]
2. List Disk [this will list all the physical disks]
3. Sel Dis X [where X is the CORRECT disk number]
4. cle [clean]
5. cre par pri [create a primary partition]
6. for fs=ntfs quick [format as NTFS]
7. act [active partition, make it bootable]
8. ass [assign a disk letter]

Comment: In order to do those steps, is there any requirement for the device prior to format like a new partition table or something?. Can you add more details?. Otherwise i dont think it is going to work.

Answer (score -1):

You most likely zeroed out not only the partition(s) and their tables but also the MBR. Try rebuilding the MBR. Without it there, your system won't even know its is a drive or disk. There are many tutorial on the web for doing this.

Comment: This is really more of a comment than an actionable solution.

Comment: Actually I zeroed the device as you mentioned since this was the only option offered in that software. However i did tried to rebuild the MBR but when i tried to create the partition it was unable because the software did not shown the capacity of the drive.

Comment: @fixer1234 It could be a solution if the MBR is missing which it most likely is and a rebuild correct it. The system was lot letting me make any comments since I haven't posted any questions and had a low rep.

Comment: I will have to research further the relatinoship between the PT and the MBR, which one needs to be created first and what specifies the size of the drive. I know there are utilities whether native to MS RE tools or third party that will read the size of a drive and calculate it. I can't imagine that any "low-level format" utility would reprogram the firmware chip on drive. There are utilities that do that. I researched that after I purchased a drive online off eBay from china that was fake. Fake thumb drives are reprogrammed as for instance 32GB when in fact they are much less, like 16GB.

Comment: Where I was going with the comment is that answers should be self-contained and actionable.  Telling someone to Google a concept and develop their own solution isn't a solution you're providing; it's a helpful hint that should go in a comment.  For an answer post, explain how to accomplish what you're recommending.  If there are already tutorials, that makes your job easier.  Find a good one, include the essential points here (or copy and paste), and include a link for attribution.

Comment: I am still now allowed to comment on others question but to answer your questions below to MikeC ... what he tells to to do in 5. Create a primary partition. that should crate the PT

Comment: This is a comment.  I randomly came across this question.  I downvote ALL commentary submitted as answers regardless of who submitted it.